# apt update connecting to my public ip

Tags: networking, apt, updates, update-manager, dns

I had an issue where my Ubuntu Server 16.04 filesystem went read only last week. I rebooted and had to do an fsck which seems to have fixed the issue and it boots and I can log in fine, however I can't do an 'apt update' anymore. When I try it tries connecting to my public IP for some reason.

What's weird is that I can ping us.archive.ubunutu.com and nslookup it and it resolves correctly.

```
broy@broyserver:/etc/apt$ ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hanger.canonical.com (91.189.91.26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=6.11 ms
64 bytes from hanger.canonical.com (91.189.91.26): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=4.02 ms
^C
--- us.archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.023/5.069/6.116/1.048 ms
broy@broyserver:/etc/apt$ nslookup us.archive.ubuntu.com
Server:         10.100.0.203
Address:        10.100.0.203#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.23
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.26
```

I replaced my actual public IP below with MYPUBLICIP. I get my IP addresses handed out via dhcp, and I am using an internal DNS server which resolves correctly. Why would my server be trying to use my own public IP to reach out to for updates?

```
broy@broyserver:/etc/apt$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to MYPUBLICIP:80 (MYPUBLICIP), connection timed out
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/0.28/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to MYPUBLICIP:80 (MYPUBLICIP), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/0.28/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to MYPUBLICIP:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't have a /etc/apt/apt.conf which may be the issue. Could someone please give me the output of what should be there so I can create it?

```
broy@broyserver:/etc/apt$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
cat: /etc/apt/apt.conf: No such file or directory
broy@broyserver:/etc/apt$
```

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
broy@broyserver:/etc/apt$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)]/ vivid main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)]/ vivid main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
broy@broyserver:/etc/apt$
```

Adding lsb-release -a

```
broy@broyserver:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Adding hosts and resolv.conf

```
broy@broyserver:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 broyserver.broyuken.com broyserver
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
broy@broyserver:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.100.0.203
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search broyuken.com
broy@broyserver:~$
```

Also adding output of $http_proxy and $https_proxy

```
broy@broyserver:~$ echo $http_proxy

broy@broyserver:~$ echo $https_proxy

broy@broyserver:~$
```

Comment: updated with the info you requested. I think the apt.conf is my issue. No clue what happened to it. Is there a backup I can restore from, or can you provide me what should be in it?

Comment: Please [edit] the output of  `lsb_release -a` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I was able to wget google.com fine, ping and nslookup work as well.

Comment: Please [edit] the content of `/etc/hosts` into your post.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` will likely also be helpful. Please [edit] that in as well.

Comment: Added, anything else you guys need?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and close this out, my security gateway was blocking apt via app control and redirecting to a usercheck page. As soon as I allowed it, things started working again